# Android multiple textview marquee

Tags: android, textview

In have the many textview which may have very long text so have done

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

For first text view it works fine but for other it is not working, if anyone have done it for other textview in activity then please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine" and what is it (not) doing when it is not working fine?

Comment: It is because only one TextView at a time can have focus. so you have to extend it. See my answer like I did.

Answer (score 7):

It is very easy extend your class with TextView and override following methods

```
package com.az.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if (focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if (focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================


}
```

and in your XML do this

```
<com.az.app.ScrollingTextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="This is a really very very very very very long text "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </RelativeLayout>
<com.az.app.ScrollingTextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="This is a really very very very very very long text "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Now all the textviews will be scrolling.

**Update:**
Note that it doesn't work without `android:singleLine="true"`.
Use it with `android:maxLines="1"`, Although we know that it's deprecated.

Comment: I'm using these in a listView and it works really well on Galaxy S4. Still works on older Galaxy 7" tab but still useable.

Comment: how does that affect accessibility?

Answer (score 0):

@Sathish Yes you can, i've done it. Following is my code for two marquee textview in xamarin.android

xml

```
<TextView
            android:text=""
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="#cc2900"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="#cc2900"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:id="@+id/txtinternational"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and in your activity you just have to set focus to your all textviews:

```
TextView shorts = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextView03);
            shorts.Selected = true;

TextView internationalshorts = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtinternational);
        internationalshorts.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 Dec and it's still an issue. Here's a TextView sub-class in kotlin that has the attributes also defined programmatically so nothing needs to be done in xml.

```
class MarqueeTextView: TextView {
    ... enter constructors ...
    init {
        ellipsize = TruncateAt.MARQUEE
        marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
        setSingleLine()
        isFocusable = true
        isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true)
    }

    override fun isFocused() = true
}
```